# Google Geochart (1.1) tooltip styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I'm using Google's Geochart and following a bunch of the examples and options here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart and generally it's been successful, but I'm curious about two things:

1. Is it possible to define the width, border etc of the `tooltip`.
2. I'm trying to change the font-size within the `tooltip` but it doesn't seem to be working.
3. Can you change the hover state to a click state, or better yet, can you have it that if you click a country something happens? Takes you to a different page etc.

I am using version 1.1 as it allows for HTML in the tooltip, but I cannot find any documentation for this anywhere.

```
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['geochart'], callback: drawVisualization});
function drawVisualization() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Country', 'Coverage', {role: 'tooltip', p:{html:true}}],
        ['United Kingdom', 2, 'Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.'],
        ['United States', 2, 'Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat.'],
        ['China', 2, 'Hello China'],
        ['Brazil', 2, '<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo6w.png"/>']
    ]);
    var options = {
        sizeAxis: { minValue: 0, maxValue: 100 },
        legend: 'none',
        tooltip: {
            isHtml: true,
            textStyle: { 
                fontSize: 21 
            }
        },
        colorAxis: {colors: ['#F1F1F1', '#4CBCBF']} // grey to cyan
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart-canvas'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}

<div id="chart-canvas" style="height:500px;"></div>
```

For the sake of all our sanity, I have set up a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/w5DYt/

Thanks,
R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Google doesn't support this, however you can manually overwrite it:

```
.google-visualization-tooltip{
    width:100px !important;
    border: 2px solid red !important;
}
```

2) the `isHtml: true` overrides your textStyle configuration, you should wrap you text in a span with a class and then use css to set your desired textStyle

3) Google doesn't support click handler, but has a selection one. You could do something like this:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart-canvas'));

function ready(){
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', handler);
    function handler(){
        var selection=chart.getSelection();
        if(selection.length==1){
            console.log(data.getValue(selection[0].row,2))
        }
    }        
}

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', ready);

chart.draw(data, options);
```

Full fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w5DYt/1/

Comment: FYI, you don't need to wrap the `select` event in a `ready` event handler.

Comment: Thanks for your help. And to @asgallant as well, but this answer was more helpful. One other thing... can you change the country font and size colour etc? I have tried everything.

Comment: @rdck try `.google-visualization-tooltip-item span{
    color:blue !important;    
}`

Comment: @juvian Works a treat. How did you manage to find that out? Bug inspector wouldn't let me.

Comment: @rdck used jquery to show html of tooltip inside the select listener ;)

Comment: I think point No. 3) isn't true:
`code
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'regionClick', function(e) {
          //alert (e['region']);        
        });
`

Comment: @FabriGadAhmed true, maybe it was removed from the documentation at least around May, as it would be strange that me and the op did not notice the event. Still, has been a long time so don´t really remember. `regionClick` should be used now

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your tooltip contents in a div and use a class (or inline styles) to style it:

**[javascript]**

```
function drawVisualization() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Country', 'Coverage', {role: 'tooltip', p:{html:true}}],
        ['United Kingdom', 2, '<div class="tooltip">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.</div>'],
        ['United States', 2, '<div class="tooltip">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat.</div>'],
        ['China', 2, '<div class="tooltip">Hello China</div>'],
        ['Brazil', 2, '<div class="tooltip">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat.</div>']
    ]);
    var options = {
        sizeAxis: { minValue: 0, maxValue: 100 },
        legend: 'none',
        tooltip: {
            isHtml: true,
            textStyle: { 
                fontSize: 21 
            }
        },
        colorAxis: {colors: ['#F1F1F1', '#4CBCBF']} // grey to cyan
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart-canvas'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

**[CSS]**

```
.tooltip {
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 50px;
}
```

There are two events you can use to capture clicks: `select` and `regionClick`.  `select` (as demonstrated by juvian) works when a user clicks on a region where there is data (UK, US, China, Brazil, in your example); `regionClick` fires when *any* region is clicked, even if it is not in your data set, and returns an object with a `region` property the holds the ISO code for the region:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'regionClick', function (e) {
    // e.region contains the ISO code for the clicked region
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/w5DYt/3/